# How to handle customized schema with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, database, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to database and server related tasks. I currently have two tables stored in a MSsql database on a server and I'm trying to use python package sqlalchemy to pull some of the data to my local machine. The first table has default schema **dbo**, and I was able to use the Connect String

`'mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>'`

to inspect the table, but the other table has a customized schema, and I don't see any information about the table when I use the previous commands. I assume it is because now the second table has different schema and the python package can't find it anymore.

I was looking at [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) hoping the package offers a way to deal with customized schema, but many concepts described in there I don't quite understand and I'm not trying to alter the database just pulling data so not sure if it's the right way, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of automap you should pass the [`schema`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.AutomapBase.prepare.params.schema) argument when preparing reflectively:

```
AutomapBase.prepare(reflect=True, schema='myschema')
```

If you wish to reflect both the default schema and your "customized schema" using the same automapper, then first reflect both schemas using the `MetaData` instance and after that prepare the automapper:

```
AutomapBase.metadata.reflect()
AutomapBase.metadata.reflect(schema='myschema')
AutomapBase.prepare()
```

If you call `AutomapBase.prepare(reflect=True, ...)` consecutively for both schemas, then the automapper will recreate and replace the classes from the 1st prepare because the tables already exist in the metadata. This will then raise warnings.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I can specify schema like that and it seems like working now! Currently I'm pulling data by using 
`query = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
engine.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.text(query))`
and I will read each row by using a for loop. Is any better way to do this? Or if I want to just load the pulled table into a pandas dataframe is there a quick way to do that?

Comment: I should have searched online before asking about the pandas dataframe. The first search result provides a solution:
`result = engine.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.text(query))
df = pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall())
df.columns = result.keys()` and so far it works out.

Comment: That works, even better. However, I just realized that even if I don't use `automap_base().prepare(.., schema='myschema')` I'm still able to get the second table with this customized schema, and  inspect of table names still returns nothing i.e. `inspector = inspect(engine)
connection = engine.connect()
# Get table information
print(inspector.get_table_names())` gives `[]`, I'm confused. So doesn't matter if I use the `schema=""` argument, I can still query the second table with customized schema and the `get_table_names()` still returns nothing, what exactly does the `automap_base()` do

Comment: Have a look at the [related docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_table_names). `get_table_names()` accepts the schema to inspect as an argument the same way the other similar reflection methods do. `automap_base()` creates a base class to use for Declarative model classes, with the automatic mapping capabilities.

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions, after add the schema argument in get_table_names() the second table showed up. There are a lot of docs and I didn't notice it, I'm digging into it now.